# why spring boot set Expires header to Expires:?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to cache control all static css/js files. the codes look like:

```
  @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/console/*.js","/console/*.css","/console/*.png","/console/*.svg")
                .addResourceLocations(
                ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "/public/console/"

        ).setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic());
    }
```

I can see the Cache-Control header is correctly set. But why the Expires is always blank ?  I'm expecting refresh for all css/js should return 304 Not Modified rather than 200 OK?

Any idea why ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Expires` is not needed anymore and recent versions of Spring adopted best practices for front-end caching (see [CacheControl](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/CacheControl.java) and the [original commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/38f32e38169f7779b9fe20d46b69024039f190ce)).

Now if you're not getting the expected result, it might be because your browser is sending a `Cache-Control: no-cache` request header. This usually happens if you've checked a "disable cache" checkbox in your browser developer tools or if you've refreshed the page with "ctrl+R".

If this is related to Spring Security, you might want to subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4307) and use [the following workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2953)

If not, please provide more information in your question (request and response headers are a good start).

Comment: hmm, it looks like spring security set Param: no-cache by default.

.headers().cacheControl().disable()

Comment: Edited my answer with Spring security